# Should the tag [64bit] be renamed into [64-bit]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Arguments for renaming the tag [64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/64bit) into [64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/64-bit):

- 64-bit seems to be the correct spelling in English, see for example the Wikipedia articles [64-bit computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) and [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64); having the correct spelling in the tag might help non-native English speakers to use it in the question (and maybe answer) text as well
- the 32-bit counterpart already reads [32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/32-bit)
- the 16-bit counterpart already reads [16-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/16-bit)

Arguments for not changing it:

- The 128-bit counterpart reads [128bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/128bit)
- There are a plethora of minor tags [7bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/7bit), [8bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/8bit), [24bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/24bit) that don't have the dash
- The [32bit-64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/32bit-64bit) tag.  Should this then change to be `[32-bit-64-bit]`?

Comment: Should it even exist? The cpu architecture itself is more relevant to group answerers by topic.

Comment: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines. With consistency a great soul has simply nothing to do. He may as well concern himself with his shadow on the wall. Speak what you think now in hard words, and to-morrow speak what to-morrow thinks in hard words again, though it contradict every thing you said to-day." - Ralph Waldo Emerson

Comment: Emerson's sentiments are terrific, and I rarely see that particular quotation so fully.  But the fullness of it does show that Emerson's particular sentiment is not really applicable to the question at hand.

Comment: It sounds like it's `[32-bit]` and `[16-bit]` that are the oddballs here.  They *are* the grammatically correct form for use in English prose, but that's a very weak argument for them to be the preferred form for tags.  If there is value in consistency here (and I think there is) then maybe it's those tags that should be changed.

Comment: Oops, I renamed the tags an hour back looking at the upvotes here, but looks like there's been some more discussion after that. Anyway, I can rename it back if it is needed. Also, @JohnBollinger, would it be possible to add that comment as an answer? That does make a lot of sense, thanks.

Comment: Possible and done, @BhargavRao.

Comment: @BhargavRao For consistency, should `[32bit]` and `[16bit]` also be added as synonyms?  Then all those "bit" tags would have both dash and non-dash versions.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, yep, I will do that once the discussion is over. Consistency FTW

Comment: What about [tag:32-bit-to-64-bit] as the rename for [tag:32bit-64bit]?  And the [tag:7bit] tag should become [tag:7-bit], and [tag:8bit] should become [tag:8-bit], and [tag:128bit] should become [tag:128-bit].  That is, they should all be consistently N-bit and (maybe) the extra word 'to' added in one case to prevent the overwork of the dash/hyphen.

Comment: Without the dash. Tags should be short and quickly type able.

Comment: @Braiam: I think (hope) `[64bit]` is supposed to be for generic / portable code that deals with 64-bit integers.  IDK if that's worth having a tag for, because it only makes sense along with other tags (like C).  Or maybe for non-portable cases like writing 32-bit x86 assembly that deals with 64-bit integers (with add/adc).  We have tags for AArch64, x86-64, mips64, etc. so `[64bit]` obviously should not be used for cases where x86-64 specifically applies, although I think that happens because not everyone realizes that x86 isn't the only CPU architecture.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's where you meet the pessimistic-me. Tags shouldn't be up to the users to interpret their usage, it should be immediately obvious what they are supposed to represent. That could work if the population was smaller and more compact about their expertise.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As John mentions in the other answer, the hyphen *is* the grammatically correct one. In a related discussion on this matter from a few years back, [Should tags take the form foobar or foo-bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/should-tags-take-the-form-foobar-or-foo-bar), it was decided to go with the hyphenated versions.

The arguments for changing just the two with hyphens to without hyphens as presented in other comments is:

- Extra Work! We need to change all the tags: This is true for a user, but a moderator can rename the tags in a jiffy, and won't take much time at all. (I can volunteer to do this.)
- People are not using the hyphenated versions: This is partially incorrect. The system prevents the users from creating a hyphenated tag when a non-hyphenated one exists. Moderators can override this.

Also, we can add the non-hyphenated versions as synonyms, which should help the users who are using the non-hyphenated versions to find the right tag.

Answer (score -2):

Adding my earlier comment as an answer:

It sounds like it's [32-bit] and [16-bit] that are the oddballs here. They are the grammatically correct form for use in English prose, but that's a very weak argument for them to be the preferred form for tags.  If there is value in consistency here (and I think there is) then maybe it's those two tags that should be changed.

Comment: Wait, why shouldn't we change *all* the tags to be grammatically correct?

Comment: I think your answer helps to bring the discussion to an important point: is the argument of the grammatical correctness really so weak in this particular case? I've seen several questions with "64bit" or "64 bit" which within the body of the text do not read well, and as a non-native English speaker I had to search the internet to find the correct spelling. My argument would be, if the correct spelling is already in the tag, maybe contributors will be more prone to use it in the text as well?

Comment: @CodyGray, I'm not arguing specifically against grammatical correctness, but rather observing that the normal usage of tags is not in a context where English grammar is meaningful.  I am furthermore observing that there is a whole family of tags here, and of those so mentioned in the (edited) question, only two are spelled with a hyphen.

Comment: I wouldn't object to changing them all to hyphenated form, but it's worth considering opting to change fewer tags, and it's also worth considering what, if anything, it means that the non-hyphenated form is currently so much more popular.

Comment: @CodyGray We already have a convention that tags not be "grammatically" correct. Words normally separated by spaces (or certain other characters) are joined with hyphens (-) instead because of the limitation on what characters can be used in tag names. The `[32bit-64bit]` tag exemplifies this, changing it to `[32-bit-64-bit]` wouldn't make it normal English usage, which would probably be "32-bit/64-bit".

Answer (score -13):

Another suggestion:

Usage in processor-architectural contexts:

```
16-bit
32-bit
64-bit
```

Anything else:

```
7bit
24bit
```

Comment: Why do you recommend this?

Comment: It seems consistent to me, it actually might be the underlying reason we ended with dashed vs. non-dashed tags in the first place. Wether this is practical enough is up for discussion now.

Comment: "It" --- it what? There's no reason behind any of this. The correct usage is not different for processor-architectural contexts and all other contexts. When you write a number with a suffix, you separate the two with a dash. The reason we ended up with these tags is someone typed them into the textbox incorrectly.

Comment: "It" certainly made sense to me with 'It' being the differentiation of "using dashes" for specifying the address witdh of memory buses for different cpu architectures vs. "not using dashes" for anything else like color depth or character encodings. I am deeply sorry for not having cleared this up better in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I believe I understood that. The question is, *why* does that make any modicum of sense to you. It certainly doesn't make any sense to me. There is no grammatical distinction between the two usages. Why should there be a distinction made in their formatting or representation? To me, it makes about as much sense as a proposal to make the tags say "bit-64". Your answer doesn't offer any justification whatsoever about why we should do this. The point of my original comment was to motivate you to [edit] the answer to contain some sort of justification or rationale.

Comment: Motivation doesnt work that way.

Comment: 24bit looks weird, besides, people probably mean 24bpp when they talk about images.

Comment: Huh?  When would `[64-bit]` ever better a better choice than `[x86-64]`, `[arm64]`, `[mips64]`. `[dec-alpha-axp]`, or whatever other 64-bit CPU architecture you're asking about?  The use-cases for `[64-bit]` include writing C that's 64-bit clean (doesn't assume that e.g. pointers and `int` are the same size, or that `long` is *not* 64-bit), or for actually dealing with 64-bit integers.  (Although we also have an `[int64]` tag..).  The use-cases do *not* include talking about x86-64 or any other *specific* architecture.

Comment: there are 24-bit architectures. There are also 4-bit, 18-bit, 36-bit, 60-bit... ones